# CRM 2015 ExecuteTransactionRquest with AssociateRequest example?

Tags: transactions, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Does anyone have a working code snippet for CreateRequest and a subsequent AssociateRequest in a CRM ExecuteTransactionRequest set? I'm searching and having no luck.

Thank you for any help :-)

**EDIT: A code snippet...**

```
var entPetition = new msd_petition();
Petition.MapEntityFromModel(entPetition, mdlPetition);
var reqPetition = new CreateRequest() { Target = entPetition };
_transactionRequest.Requests.Add(reqPetition);

// Add PetitionEvents to transaction
foreach (var mdlEvent in mdlPetition.Events)
{
    var entEvent = new msd_petitionevent();
    PetitionEvent.MapEntityFromModel(entEvent, mdlEvent);
    var reqEvent = new CreateRequest() { Target = entEvent };
    _transactionRequest.Requests.Add(reqPetition);
    // Add Petition-PetitionEvent association
    var assocPetition2PetitionEvent = new AssociateRequest()
    {
        Target = new EntityReference(msd_petition.EntityLogicalName, entPetition.msd_petitionId.Value),
        RelatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection
        {
            new EntityReference(sevp_petitionevent.EntityLogicalName, entEvent.msd_petitioneventId.Value)
        },
        Relationship = new Relationship("msd_petition_petitionevent")
    };
    _transactionRequest.Requests.Add(assocPetition2PetitionEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the second `AssociateRequest`. You can achieve the same using just the `CreateRequest` and `Entity.RelatedEntites` property. It would be executed as a single transaction.

```
var entPetition = new msd_petition();
Petition.MapEntityFromModel(entPetition, mdlPetition);

var petitionPetitionEventRelationship = new Relationship("msd_petition_petitionevent");
var petitionRelatedEvents = new EntityCollection();

// Add PetitionEvents to transaction
foreach (var mdlEvent in mdlPetition.Events)
{
    var entEvent = new msd_petitionevent();
    PetitionEvent.MapEntityFromModel(entEvent, mdlEvent);
    petitionRelatedEvents.Entities.Add(entEvent);
}

entPetition.RelatedEntities.Add(petitionPetitionEventRelationship, petitionRelatedEvents);

service.Create(entPetition);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that won't work with my code. I added a sample to the OP. But thank you!

Comment: @Locohost In your example I noticed that `reqEvent` is not added to create request. Also should `sevp_petitionevent.EntityLogicalName` be changed to `msd_petitionevent.EntityLogicalName`?. I have updated my answer to reflect you code snippet.

Comment: I'm working on a different approach using context.AddObject and context.AddRelatedObject. If this works, I'm good, if not, I'll try your example next. *Thank you!!*

Comment: I did end up using your method of batch create. It works! Thank for that. I'll accept your answer. May I ask a quick followup? In my "Update" code (which is very similar to the "Create" code) I can't add the updated related entities to the related entities collection. I get a "collection is read-only" error. Have you seen this? Any suggestion?

Comment: I figured out the read-only issue. I'll update my OP to show some sample create and update code that works